# Typescript compiler error when using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm currently trying to setup my first react project using redux and run in a compiler error right from the start.

I installed redux and redux toolkit like this:

> npm install @reduxjs/toolkit react-redux

Then I added a `store.ts` file with this content

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {}
})
```

When I try to compile the project I get the following error message:

> [09:54:12] Error - [tsc]
> ../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/createSlice.d.ts(128,125): error
> TS1005: '?' expected. [09:54:12] Error - [tsc]
> ../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/createSlice.d.ts(128,154): error
> TS1005: ';' expected. [09:54:12] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after
> 8

My typscript version is 3.9.10

Any Ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: maybe you should pass a reducer to it

Comment: thats not the problem. Even if the file has only the import I get that error

Answer (score 3):

That is an extremely outdated version of TypeScript. Redux Toolkit usually supports the last 5 minor versions of TypeScript at the release of the RTK version - at the moment that would be TS>=4.4

Comment: That absolutely makes sense and I thought I would be using a recent version (didn't check it though). Somehow node doesn't update the used typescript version. In the `package.json` i have the entry `"typescript": "^4.9.3"` under `devDependencies` but it still uses version 3.9.10. I'm running the project with gulp

Comment: For installing packages, you would be using a package manager like npm, yarn or pnpm. I don't think that's gulps job.

Comment: Yes, thats not what I meant. I installed everything with npm. I tried reinstalling and upgrading. But as soon as I run the project with gulp it uses the old tsc version. I thought it might have something to do with gulp

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and while I also think it has to do with my app using an older version of TypeScript (unfortunately upgrading to a later version was not an option, it broke too much stuff), what worked for me was just going down to version 1.8.6 of redux/toolkit. Hope this helps.